# set default location to download to using the file class in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I have a exe file I want to download, using a url.

I'm using the File class and calling the download(url) function to download the file.

This lets me choose a place to download the file, but the default is either the path of the application directory or the last place the user choose to save a file. This sometimes causes problems because the user will try to save it to their application directory, but we don't allow them to have write access to the folder.

I want to be able to set the default to somewhere like the downloads folder. Is there a work around to achieve this?

update: Actually i found the answer. you just place the path in the file creation. var file:File = new File("path");

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you meant to ask about the [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) class because the [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) class doesn't have a `download` function.

From the asdoc on FileReference:

> The FileReference and FileReferenceList classes do not let you set the default file location for the dialog box that the browse() or download() methods generate